# R syntax of a second-order factor analysis. Does it work if one factor from the first order only consists of 2 items?

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor, error-message

I tried the following syntax:

```r
MTX0 <- '

# First-order factors
StwR1t0_latent =~ S1pR1t0 + S2pR1t0 + S3pR1t0
RtwR1t0_latent =~ R1pR1t0 + R2pR1t0
TtwR1t0_latent =~ T1pR1t0 + T2pR1t0 + T3pR1t0 + T4pR1t0
GtwR1t0_latent =~ G1pR1t0 + G2pR1t0 + G3pR1t0

# Second-order factor
MuTex =~ StwR1t0_latent + RtwR1t0_latent + TtwR1t0_latent + GtwR1t0_latent

StwR1t0_latent ~~ RtwR1t0_latent  
StwR1t0_latent ~~ TtwR1t0_latent  
StwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent  
RtwR1t0_latent ~~ TtwR1t0_latent  
RtwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent  
TtwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent
'


#Modell berechnen für Effect Coding mit Meanstructure
fitMTX0<- cfa(MTX0, data=dataMaster012 , missing="fiml" , estimator="mlr" , meanstructure=T , auto.fix.first=F)
summaryCfa<-summary(fitMTX0, fit.measures=T, standardized=T, modindices=T)
summaryCfa
```

I get the following error message:

```r
Error in modificationIndices(object, standardized = TRUE, cov.std = cov.std) : 
  lavaan ERROR: could not compute modification indices; information matrix is singular
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In lav_fit_cfi_lavobject(lavobject = object, fit.measures = fit.measures,  :
  lavaan WARNING: computation of robust CFI failed.
2: In lav_fit_rmsea_lavobject(lavobject = object, fit.measures = fit.measures,  :
  lavaan WARNING: computation of robust RMSEA failed.
3: In sqrt(var.lhs.value * var.rhs.value) : NaNs produced
4: In lav_start_check_cov(lavpartable = lavpartable, start = START) :
  lavaan WARNING: starting values imply NaN for a correlation value;
                  variables involved are: StwR1t0_latent RtwR1t0_latent
```

Can anyone help with this problem? Is it possible that one of the first order factors only consists of 2 items?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are allowing your first-order factor residuals to correlate in addition to the first-order factors being indicators of a second-order factor. This leads to an underidentified model that also does not make sense conceptually (the second-order factor should account for all or at least most of the associations of the first-order factors). Deleting the last set of commands

StwR1t0_latent ~~ RtwR1t0_latent
StwR1t0_latent ~~ TtwR1t0_latent
StwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent
RtwR1t0_latent ~~ TtwR1t0_latent
RtwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent
TtwR1t0_latent ~~ GtwR1t0_latent

through which you specify the first-order factor residual correlations should help.

It is OK for a first-order factor to have only two indicators as long as that factor is substantially correlated with one of the other factors in the model (i.e., as long as that factor loads substantially on the g factor)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, when I remove those commands, the model fit is not acceptable. My original model was without these last set of commands. After inspecting the modification indices, it seemed that the model could be improved by adding the last commands to the syntax. I understand that allowing the first-order factor residuals to correlate does not make sense conceptually and on top leads to an underidentified model . However, I'm wondering if there could be any other errors in the code or if you have any other recommendations to further enhance the model fit?